# How to Casting Object(by Type.InvokeMember) to ObservableCollection<ReflectionType>?

Tags: observablecollection

When I got the object by calling `Type.InvokeMember()`, the Object Type is
`Object{ObervableCollection<SomeType>`

How can I Casting this object to original type? or how to casting the object to `DataTable` or `List<OriginalType>`?